# How to convert the dropdown menu to label once the value is selected.and again convert into the dropdown onclick of the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have dialog on which different dropdowns are there if i select the value then it the selected value will be shown as label and there is a button in side as "Change" so if user click on change then again label will be converted into dropdown. 
the same thing for the other dropdown

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would do this as 2 separate controls. Have the drop-down available, with the label hidden. Once they select the value, set the label text to the value, then show the label. Have the button hide the label again, showing the drop-down...

Answer (score 0):

Have a span near the dropdown. when the option is selected, update the span with the selected value using jquery. Then hide the dropdown

using this code you can get the selected value and update it in the span tag and it will display as label and then you can hide the dropdown box

```
$("# dropdown id").change(function () {
    //update the value in to span
    $('# span id').html($('# dropdown id').val());
    $('# dropdown id').hide();
});
```

When you click the change button, you can show the hidden dropdown box and hide the span tag.